# element need to be sticked to bottom (position:absolute) vs part of the DOM (position:relative)

Tags: javascript, floating

I have a requirement where element need to be sticked to bottom (position:absolute) vs part of the DOM (position:relative)

UseCase "footer" stick to bottom (position:absolute) when elementA and elementB are not in view. "footer" position relative when elementA is not in view, elementB is in view. "footer" position relative when elementA, elementB both in view.

tried waypoint, offsets. having jittery flashing footer when elementB comes into view while scrolling. I do not think observer api is helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know precisely what problems you're having with the Observer API, but if [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) isn't flexible enough for you then [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) does sound like your best bet.

You mention a footer so perhaps you want `position: fixed` rather than `position: absolute`?

```js
const b = document.getElementById("b");
const sticky = document.getElementById("sticky");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (entry?.isIntersecting) {
    // b is fully visible
    sticky.style.position = "relative";
    sticky.style.bottom = "";
  }
  else {
    sticky.style.position = "fixed";
    sticky.style.bottom = 0;
  }
}, { threshold: 1.0 });

observer.observe(b);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#a {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}

#sticky {
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#sticky div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div id="a">This is A</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div id="b">This is B</div>
<div id="sticky">
  <div>Sticky footer</div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```